# libVLCQtCore.so: undefined reference to `qt_version_tag@Qt_5.11'

Tags: linux, qt, libvlc, vlc-qt

wanna to make a simple media player by [vlc-qt](https://vlc-qt.tano.si/) on Linux, but when I tried to construct the [example

project](https://github.com/vlc-qt/examples/tree/master/simple-player) downloaded, It only told me :

```
libVLCQtCore.so: undefined reference to `qt_version_tag@Qt_5.11'
```

So, what should I do?

more details:

OS: Ubuntu 18.10

QMake version 3.1

Qt version 5.8.0

And here is the .pro file:

```
#
# VLC-Qt Simple Player
# Copyright (C) 2015 Tadej Novak <tadej@tano.si>
#

TARGET      = simple-player
TEMPLATE    = app
CONFIG     += c++11

QT         += widgets

SOURCES    += main.cpp \
    SimplePlayer.cpp \
    EqualizerDialog.cpp

HEADERS    += SimplePlayer.h \
    EqualizerDialog.h

FORMS      += SimplePlayer.ui \
    EqualizerDialog.ui




# Edit below for custom library location
#LIBS       += -L/Users/tadej/workspace/tanoprojects/install/vlc-qt/lib -lVLCQtCore -lVLCQtWidgets
#INCLUDEPATH += /Users/tadej/workspace/tanoprojects/install/vlc-qt/include

#LIBS       += -lVLCQtCore -lVLCQtWidgets
INCLUDEPATH += /usr/local/include
LIBS += -L/usr/local/lib -lVLCQtCore
LIBS += -L/usr/local/lib -lVLCQtWidgets
LIBS += -L/usr/local/lib -lVLCQtQml
```

---

```
yeoman@Inspiron-7560:~$ ldd /usr/local/lib/libVLCQtCore.so
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffe5f834000)
    libQt5Core.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5 (0x00007ff7df18b000)
    libvlc.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvlc.so.5 (0x00007ff7df165000)
    libvlccore.so.9 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvlccore.so.9 (0x00007ff7df05b000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007ff7deed1000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007ff7deeb7000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007ff7deccd000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007ff7decaa000)
    libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007ff7dea8d000)
    libicui18n.so.60 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicui18n.so.60 (0x00007ff7de5ec000)
    libicuuc.so.60 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicuuc.so.60 (0x00007ff7de235000)
    libdouble-conversion.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdouble-conversion.so.1 (0x00007ff7de024000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007ff7de01e000)
    libglib-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0 (0x00007ff7ddeff000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007ff7ddd72000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007ff7df769000)
    libidn.so.11 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libidn.so.11 (0x00007ff7ddd3d000)
    libdbus-1.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdbus-1.so.3 (0x00007ff7ddcee000)
    libicudata.so.60 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicudata.so.60 (0x00007ff7dc145000)
    libpcre.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3 (0x00007ff7dc0cf000)
    libsystemd.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsystemd.so.0 (0x00007ff7dc045000)
```

Comment: what is the output of  `ldd /path/of/libVLCQtCore.so`?

Comment: I have updated the question, and you can see it ;)

Comment: As noted by the libVLCQtCore.so has been compiled with Qt 5.11 but you point out that you have Qt 5.8, have you compiled vlc-qt on your PC?

Comment: I compiled it yesterday, btw I haven't install Qt5.11, but how can it be.

Comment: Do not ask me, it's your PC, I recommend you uninstall vlc-qt and compile it back with Qt 5.8

Comment: Have you compiled it or used the ppa?

Comment: compile using the following: https://github.com/vlc-qt/vlc-qt/blob/master/BUILDING.md#linux

Comment: OK, and really appreciate your help